Provide full data on DSPJRN output file
I'm using the command DSPJRN having the parameter OUTPUT(*OUTFILE). One of the output file column is JOESD which contains the specific data for the journal. But the field length is only 100. Is there a way to make it more than 100 so that I don't need to check one by one for the entries in order to the complete data?

You need to use something besides the defaults for the DSPJRN parameters.
In particular the, Entry Data Length (ENTDTALEN) parameter and the Outfile format (OUTFILFMT).
OUTFILFMT(*TYPE5) and ENTDTALEN(*CALC)
Will provide basically everything available.  There are other options however.
